# I just updated an angular project from ver 6 to 15 but whenever i try the project it brings the following error

Tags: javascript, font-awesome, angular15

Error: src/app/app.module.ts:38:5 - error NG6002: 'Angular2FontawesomeModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.

38     Angular2FontawesomeModule,
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/angular2-fontawesome/src/index.d.ts:1:22
1 export declare class Angular2FontawesomeModule {
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
This likely means that the library (angular2-fontawesome) which declares Angular2FontawesomeModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

I tried modifying the import statement from "import { Angular2FontawesomeModule } from 'angular2-fontawesome/angular2-fontawesome'"
to "import { Angular2FontawesomeModule } from 'angular2-fontawesome';"
in the app.modules.ts

Comment: [angular2-fontawesome](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-fontawesome) has not received any updates since 5 years, development has stopped. It is not compatible with Angular 15, that's what the error tells you. What exactly is your question? Everything is clear in my perspective. In order to update to Angular 15, you need to get rid of that dependency.

Comment: thank you, I didn't know  that its development has stopped